# Problematic tags displaying HTML in Java

Tags: java, meta-tags, jeditorpane

I have the following tag included in my HTML which causes the JEditorPane not to show the HTML output.

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Not so much a big deal but anyone know why this would happen?

Cannot find too much documentation on this - best I came up with was someone having a go a few years ago to see what was supported on [retro virus site](http://retrovirus.com/brunch/2003/04/html-support-in-jeditorpane/).

At the minute I'm doing a simple find replace on the string which is not good - are there any better ways?  I've seen a lot of people saying that RegEx is no good.

The code I have used is

```
this._html = this._html.replace( "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">", "");
```

Andez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx is not good for parsing the full HTML document. But in this case, I don't find any problem going with that.

Regarding your former question, I really don't have no idea.

Comment: The only problem with the way I have done it is that any extra white space in the META string would cause the replace to fail as it would not find it!!

Comment: @Andez: Okay. So, would mind showing the code here. Just update your question to add that.

Comment: I have updated my question with my work around.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Andez: That seems okay to me.